# Chrome Javascript Sources converting import module name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In my original source code, I have

```
import myconst from '../utils/constants';
case myconst.XYZ:
```

However, in the Chrome Javascript source, I see the same converted as

```
case _myAppUtilsConstants['default'].XYZ:
```

It also says define(...) for the imported module

Is there some setting to prevent this conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't currently support ES2016, so you use transpilers like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to convert ES2016 code into ES5 code. What you're seeing in Chrome is the generated ES5 code.

You can use [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) to tell Chrome how your original code relates to the code that runs inside Chrome.

For example, Babel has a [sourceMaps option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) and Webpack can also [generate a source map](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool).

How this works specifically depends on the setup you are using to transpile your ES6 code.

You may have to [enable source maps in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps) first.